# Python, не работает парсер

Tags: python, парсер

написала парсер на языке программирования Python (3.8), по неизвестной мне причине ничего не отображается, даже ошибки.

Вот мой код:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def parse():
  URL = 'https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/muzhchinam/odezhda/vodolazki'
  HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
  }



  response = requests.get(URL,headers = HEADERS)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
  items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'dtList-innerr')
  comps = []

  for item in items:
    try:
        comps.append({
          'title': item.find('span', class_ = 'goods-name c-text-sm').get_text(strip = True),
          'price': item.find('span', class_ = 'price').get_text(strip = True),
          'link': item.find('a', class_ = 'ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card').get('href')
        })
    except:
        pass

  global comp
  for comp in comps:
    print(f'{comp["title"]} -> Price: {comp["price"]} -> Link: {comp["link"]}')
  
parse()
```

Comment: Дебаж. Что еще можно сказать? Если нет вывода, то bs4 скорее всего ничего не нашел.

Comment: Попробуй: `except Exception as e:  print(str(e))`

Comment: можно полный код с изменениями?

Comment: вероятно items - пустой

Comment: Может и items пустой, кстати.

Comment: Делала парсер с таким же кодом для другого сайта. Ошибок не было, и все работало.

Comment: icYFTL можете пожалуйста скинуть полный код с вашими изменнениями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас всего лишь ошибка в названии класса, который вы ищете - лишняя буква `r` в конце.
Вот с таким названием класса всё работает: `dtList-inner`.
Полезно всё-таки знать английский язык.
Ну и проверять, что вообще ищет ваш код руками в `response` (а есть ли это вообще там) - тоже полезно.

```
items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'dtList-inner') # удалил лишнюю букву
```

Comment: Она должна была дойти до этого сама.

Comment: @icYFTL Извините. Не догадался ))

Answer (score 0):

Ищите проблему в `items` или в блоке `try` отладкой или:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def parse():
  URL = 'https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/muzhchinam/odezhda/vodolazki'
  HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
  }

  response = requests.get(URL,headers = HEADERS)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
  items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'dtList-innerr')
  comps = []
  print(items)  # Pseudo-debug

  for item in items:
    try:
        comps.append({
          'title': item.find('span', class_ = 'goods-name c-text-sm').get_text(strip = True),
          'price': item.find('span', class_ = 'price').get_text(strip = True),
          'link': item.find('a', class_ = 'ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card').get('href')
        })
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))  # Pseudo-debug

  global comp
  for comp in comps:
    print(f'{comp["title"]} -> Price: {comp["price"]} -> Link: {comp["link"]}')


parse()
```

Comment: File "pars3.py", line 12
    response = requests.get(URL,headers = HEADERS)
                                                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Ошибка, я знаю что дело в отступах, но не знаю где их поставить, если что сейчас я вставила вашу версию из ответа

Comment: Я куски кода изменил. Очевидно что если вставить мой код вместо Вашего, то ничего работать не будет

Comment: Вставьте лучше принты куда надо и измените `except` так, как у меня

Comment: я вставила не только ваш код, я вставила этот кусок кода вместо моего куска кода, и проблема с отступами. Я прошу вас взять мой код заменить кусок мой на ваш, и сделать нормальные отступы. Пожалуйста :)

Comment: Изменил. Но дальше мне критически лень что-то делать

Comment: вот что вывелось с вашим кодом : []

Comment: Ну и все. Очевидно, что items пустая. Следовательно for пролетает

Comment: И как мне решить проблему?)

Comment: bs4 не нашел ничего что подходит под `soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'dtList-innerr')` . Дальше ничем помочь не могу